# I have a new Nintendo 3DS XL and I want to use my Animal Crossing on the new platform

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My old Nintendo 3DS XL kept stopping so I bought a refurbished Nintendo 3DS XL. I put in my old game cartridge, but the menu is so confusing I am afraid to answer the questions the wrong way (when I am on the train) because I don't want to destroy the town I have built up over the last 2 years.

I just want to have the same town on a new Nintendo 3DS XL platform.  How do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can't you simply load your old saved game?

Comment: This sounds more like your saved data is still on your old 3DS and not your new one so you are starting a new game completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you bought a physical copy of the game, the save data for ACNL will save on the Game Card. Just put it in there and you should have your town right where you left off.